# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'

Tags: postgresql, docker, jmeter

I'm facing an issue in the JMeter run, where while running the JMeter using the docker it is happening. In the JMeter, it is working fine. But in the terminal, by using docker this error is coming.

Not using maven. I'm just running the below-mentioned docker command.

sudo docker run --mount type=bind,source="/home/user/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/",target="/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin" jmeter -n -t bin/Assignment2.jmx -l bin/example-run29.jtl

This is the jtl file result that I'm getting after the run.

timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1621688749004,13,JDBC Request,null 0,java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver',Thread Group 1-1,text,false,,53,0,1,1,null,0,0,13

Comment: Please [edit] the post and provide the full stack trace, the dockerfile and some details of your project setup (e.g. relevant parts of the `pom.xml` if you are using maven).

Comment: Could you provide your Dockerfile?

Comment: Not using maven. I'm just running the below-mentioned docker command.

sudo docker run --mount type=bind,source="/home/user/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/",target="/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin" jmeter -n -t bin/Assignment2.jmx -l bin/example-run29.jtl

Comment: @ErangaHeshan This is the jtl file result that I'm getting after the run.




timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1621688749004,13,JDBC Request,null 0,java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver',Thread Group 1-1,text,false,,53,0,1,1,null,0,0,13

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) in the [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) so you need to either [copy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) the file (it should be something like `postgresql-xx.x.xx.jar`, the latest one is https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.2.20/postgresql-42.2.20.jar or amend your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) to automatically download this driver and place it to the JMeter Classpath, something like:

```
RUN wget wget https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.20.jar
RUN mv postgresql-42.2.20.jar /path/to/your/jmeter/lib
```

More information: [How to use Different JDBC Drivers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732729-How-to-use-Different-JDBC-Drivers-How-to-use-Different-JDBC-Drivers)